# How to exclude some words from the search in a regular expression?

Tags: regex

I tried to make some syntax checker for arithmetic expressions.
So, one of the negative tests is: No operator between variable(or constant) and left brace. Something like that:

```
    if (expression.matches(".*[a-zA-Z|0-9]+\\(.*")) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Syntax error in the expression: " + expression);
        }
```

But I need to use functions(like sin, cos etc.) in expressions in the following format: sin(number), so the test doesn't work, because the rule above says that some operator
between "sin" and "(" is needed.

Is it possible to add exceptions in the rule above to use sin, cos, tan, cot, etc.?
I mean something like (^sin|cos|tan|cot)
Or do I need to edit the syntax rules in my regex at all?

Comment: Do you mean you need to add a rule to fail the match if a string contains `sin`, `cos`, `tan` ot `cot`? Like `"(?!.*\\b(?:co[ts]|tan|sin)\\b).*[a-zA-Z|0-9]+\\(.*"`?

Comment: Yes. But your rule doesn't work( I just tried this for cos(1+2)+sin(a)-(3+2)

Comment: It does not work because.... Do not just say "it does not work", because it works, but most likely not the way you expect. What do you expect? Show some test cases.

Comment: -cos(1+2)+sin(a)-var*(3+2)   = correct (must fail the match)
const(1+2)+const123(a)-tan*(3+2)   = not correct (doesn't fail the match )

Comment: Try `".*[a-zA-Z0-9](?<!\\b(?:co[ts]|tan|sin))\\(.*"`

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```java
if (expression.matches(".*[a-zA-Z0-9](?<!\\b(?:co[ts]|tan|sin))\\(.*")) {...}
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ULd9Zf/1).

*Details*:

- `.*` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]` - an alphanumeric char
- `(?<!\b(?:co[ts]|tan|sin))` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there is `cos`, `cot`, `tan` or `sin` whole word immediately to the left of the current location
- `\(`  - a literal `(` char
- `.*` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible.